# Revit project browser organization through RPW, python and the revit API

Tags: revit-api, pyrevit

is it possible to expand/collapse items (ie views, sheets, legends, etc) in the Revit project browser window through the Revit API and RPW

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, the only API access currently available for the project browser are the [methods provided by the `BrowserOrganization` class](https://apidocs.co/apps/revit/2019/df50516e-3617-8c25-13dd-1f06bef324d3.htm).

Comment: Jeremy is correct. There is no API available. Please accept his answer.